# Increase the height of dropdown box for AutoComplete

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am using the AutoComplete component in my Flex website. Everything is fine, but there is one issue.

If i type something in the text area, and the items that are searched are alot, i want to increase the height of the dropdown box.  I am unable to figure that out.

below is the code to my autocomplete

```
<auto:AutoComplete borderStyle="none" id="txt_global_search" 
        textAlign="left" prompt="Search Content" 
        dataProvider="{global_search_list}" 
        allowEditingNewValues="true" allowMultipleSelection="true" allowNewValues="true" 
        backspaceAction="remove" 
        labelField="label" 
        width="200" height="23" right="400"  top="1"
        autoSelectEnabled="false" 
        matchType="anyPart" 
        keyUp="{event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER?openItemWindow():searchChange()}"           
        dropDownItemRenderer="{new ClassFactory(indexCloud.index_cloud_global_search_item_renderer)}" />
```

Regards
Zeeshan

Answer (score 1):

Which AutoComplete are you using?

With the Flextras AutoComplete ( http://www.flextras.com/?event=ProductHome&ProductID=10 ); you can extend the height of the drop down box by specifying the rowcount property.  The Flex ComboBox works similarly.

It is possible your the component you're using offers similar functionality.